# iOS 10: NSUserDefaults resets after user installs new adhoc version

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, ios10, ad-hoc-distribution

We use enterprise deployment to deploy versions of an app to users. Since iOS 10 we have the problem that the app "forgets" the settings in `NSUserDefaults` after installing a new version of the app. The behaviour seems to be a problem with the enterprise version only and not with the App Store version. The code and the defaults are the same.

Is there any fix to this or is it "just" a iOS 10 bug?

Comment: after delete + reinstall? or just after an update?

Comment: No, just after installing it using the HockeyApp SDK (which uses links like itms-service:// )

Comment: if you referred to a clean install, then there is no previous _User Defaults_ are available for such scenario.

Comment: I know but as I wrote the app is not deleted during that process

Comment: Also it does not happen every time which makes it particularly hard to debug